# blob garbage collection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, garbage-collection

I'm attempting to use the html5 file input functions by **kartik**@ to upload a large amount of images. I would prefer that the end user didn't have to resize images prior to uploading so I am using the **resizeImage option**@. I run into issues when uploading large files (3-4MB each).

I have modified fileinput.js to replace the preview image with the resized blob, however my browser (Chrome 48.0.2564.103 m) still lists the original (large filesize) blob in the F12 -> Resources -> ... -> Images folder. When uploading hundreds of images, the browser will eventually run out of memory and crash.

I can't find any reference to the original/large blob in the 'self' object of fileinput.js so I'm at a loss as to how to have this unused blob garbage collected.

[jsfiddle of issue](http://jsfiddle.net/birmas/dc7jgd7p/4/) / [link to modified fileinput.js](http://bit.ly/1NRhzr7) (modifications made :2396-2412)

```
                   setTimeout(function(d) {
                    console.log('attempting to replace original blob with:');
                    console.log(blob);
                    console.log(objUrl.createObjectURL(blob));
                    console.log('attempting to revoke original blob: ' + image.src);
                    objUrl.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
                    delete image.src;
                    self.clearDefaultPreview();
                    image.src = objUrl.createObjectURL(blob);
                    console.log('outputting fileinput.js self var:');
                    console.dir(JSON.stringify(self));
                    console.dir(self);

                }, 500);
            }, type, self.resizeQuality);

            console.log('current image.src blob is: ' + image.src);
```

@I don't have the reputation to post more than two links, so I have embedded links to the plugin documentation within the javascript frame on jsfiddle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to call revokeObjectURL() once for every time you call createObjectURL()

Comment: createObjectURL() is only being called once for the large blob, the calls in the source listed above referencing 'blob' are the small blob

Comment: all those console logs take a lot of RAM to keep around. also, i'm not at all surprised that a browser tab can't resize hundreds of multi-megabyte images without crashing. we need to see the rest of your code to be of more help; it that in a loop? where do hundreds of images come in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what other source I can post beyond what is in the jsfiddle? Whether I'm adding one image, ten or a hundred - there is a problem with the blob remaining in memory, which I thought revokeObjectURL() should be cleaning up. I've profiled the example in both chrome and firefox and both report that the large (3+MB) blobs are remaining in memory.

Comment: the logs themselves probably keep a reference to the blob alive. remove logging.

Comment: I figured out what was going on, the fileinput script wasn't resizing the blobs until after all images had been preloaded. After modifying it to process each image one at a time, my performance was working as well as could be expected with such large images - Thank you guys for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on, the fileinput script wasn't resizing the blobs until after all images had been preloaded. After modifying it to process each image one at a time, my performance was working as well as could be expected with such large images - Thank you guys for your comments.